# Client keeps requesting file from REST API

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have an audio file stored on the server and clients can request these audio files via a REST API. I observed the data requested by the client and I came to the conclusion whenever I play the audio again (repeat), then a new request goes to the server for that specific file. Is there a way to prevent this or cache the data locally?

HTML

```
<audio controls="controls" autoplay style="width: 100%">
    <source src="https://localhost:8080/api/file" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Javascript (Node.js in combination with Express.js)

```
router.get('/file', (req, res) => {
    let audioFile = path.join(__dirname, 'files/audio-book.mp3');
    res.sendFile(audioFile);
})
```

**EDIT**

I have a local file and a file sent by the REST API. The local file request has HTTP code `304: Not modified` and the file from the REST API request is `206: Partial content`. I already added `max-age` and removed `last-modified`, but no result.

Headers:

```
Accept-Ranges -> Bytes
Cache-Control -> public, max-age=3600
Connection -> keep-alive
Content-Length -> 7056954
Content-Type -> audio/mpeg
Date -> Sun, 17 Jan 2016 10:16:48 GMT
Etag -> W/"6bae3a-15195a7f2aa"
X-Powered-By → Express
```

Comment: You can try  set [Cache-Control](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3) header `res.header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=3600').`

Comment: @Darth Client still makes another request to the API for that specific file.

Comment: Checkout browser network tab, are you sure it's not 304?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly I have the two files setup to compare them and the local file is ``304`` and the file from the REST API is ``206``.

Comment: 206 (__Partial Content__) - _The server is delivering only part of the resource (byte serving) due to a range header sent by the client. The range header is used by HTTP clients to enable resuming of interrupted downloads, or split a download into multiple simultaneous streams._

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly I knew that, but what is a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

**Situation**

What happened was that the browser wouldn't cache the file in any way, shape or form. This let to tremendous amounts of traffic.

**Solution**

I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004381/play-mp3-file-stored-as-blob) on StackOverflow about requesting files in blobs and letting an audio- or video element play it. Now I XHR the file from the server and store it in a BLOB and when I replay the audio, it retrieves the data from cache and it can work offline now.