# PHP: read as audio file from MySQL BLOB data

Tags: php, mysql, blob

How can I read a `BLOB` data from `MySQL` table as **audio file** in `PHP` and use `<audio>` tag in `HTML` to present it?

I have tried to do that like this, but it doesn't work.

```
echo "<audio controls> <source src=\"".$data."\" type=\"audio/wav\"> </audio>";
```

Comment: Please show the *relevant* code that you have tried, not the html what you are showing us

Comment: consider $data as blog output of mysql data which is in fact an audio file.. i cant show you exact code as it is developed with different classes.

Comment: Why putting them into database instead of storing _files_ on _filesystem_ where you easily can link the files?

Comment: Lots of things could affect this. Browser support, blob data not loaded, wrong mime type.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004381/play-mp3-file-stored-as-blob

Comment: We have multiple asterisk servers which record the voicemails and we need a single node to access all voicemails from different servers for same user.